# How can I run as root on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, root, sudo, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I tried using `sudo` to run a command on Heroku. Then I get a message that I cannot use the sudo command on Heroku. My real question is: How can I run a command with root privilege on Heroku, because it is required for some of the commands I'm trying to run?

Comment: Are you trying to run it over CLI?

Answer (score 9):

You cannot run as root on a Heroku Dyno, as Dynos are effectively containers, isolated from the host system. However, you should be able to install most packages via Buildpacks, either via first party [supported buildpacks](https://github.com/heroku?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=heroku-buildpack), [thirdparty buildpacks](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/), or via [heroku-buildpack-apt](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt). Attempting to alter any system files, will likely either not work, or will have unintended consequences.

Comment: I understand that build packs are to be used to install packages in heroku. I used the heroku-buildpack-apt to install a `.deb` package. Now how do I install it?